# Activity gauge High Chart with Gradient

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts, gradient, gauge

I want to use gradient in below chart.

Please help me on this concern.

Thanks in advance.

```
  Link : http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.9.1/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/gauge-activity/
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by gradient? Could you please post an image showing what you would like to achieve?

Comment: Hello I have added Image actually what i want.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be able to use small trick for adding gradient to your angular gauge. You can use yAxis.stops for adding color gradients to your chart:

```
yAxis: {
  min: 0,
  max: 100,
  lineWidth: 0,
  tickPositions: [],
  stops: [
    [0.1, '#55BF3B'], // green
    [0.5, '#DDDF0D'], // yellow
    [0.9, '#DF5353'] // red
  ],
},
```

Then you can add points between your axis min and your value, so they will have different colors depending on points value.

```
function(chart) {
    var y = this.series[0].data[0].y;
    for (var i = y; i >= 0; i = i - (y / 80)) {
      chart.addSeries({
        data: [{
          y: i,
          radius: '100%',
          innerRadius: '100%',
        }],
        stickyTracking: false,
        enableMouseTracking: false
      }, false)
    }
    chart.redraw();
    Highcharts.each(chart.series, function(s) {
      s.update({
        borderColor: s.data[0].color
      }, false);
    });
    chart.redraw();
  }
```

Here you can find an example how it can work:
http://jsfiddle.net/5ajoegb9/1/

Comment: Yeahhh Thanks for the update. I want something like this but i want two circle in the graph. I have attached it on proposal.

Comment: Yeah I am done it. Thanks a lot... Thanks you very much for your help. You make my day. You save my lots of time.

Comment: Hello @Grzegorz Blachliński, I need your help regarding this chart again, I am really appreciating your effort. Please get back to me. I want rang in a chart like display in the question.

Comment: I am not sure what precisely you want to have on your chart

Comment: what I need is a a chart with gradient as shown in above image. I have two circles and I want them to show in clock-wise(outer circle) and anti-clock-wise (inner circle). As shown in the second image. Thanks.