# Activity gauge High Chart with Range option

Tags: javascript, jquery, charts, highcharts, gauge

I have used activity gauge from the HighChart. I want activity gauge chart with the range option in data. See the below example:

Suppose my yAxis have a min and max value 0 to 100.

```
 yAxis: {
          min: 0,
          max: 100
}
```

I want series data in a range option like below

```
series: [{
          data: [{
            y: [0,48]
          },{
            y: [90,100]
         }
        }]
```

I want same like below image
[image]

I also want custom tool tip like below image

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Similar topic was here: 
[Activity gauge High Chart with Gradient](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39594440/activity-gauge-high-chart-with-gradient)

As an addition to this topic, you can use different panes that will start and end in different positions:

```
pane: [{
  startAngle: 0,
  endAngle: 360,
  background: [{ // Track for Move
    outerRadius: '112%',
    innerRadius: '88%',
    backgroundColor: Highcharts.Color(Highcharts.getOptions().colors[0]).setOpacity(0.3).get(),
    borderWidth: 0
  }]
}, {
  startAngle: 360,
  endAngle: 0,
  background: [{ // Track for Move
    outerRadius: '72%',
    innerRadius: '48%',
    backgroundColor: Highcharts.Color(Highcharts.getOptions().colors[0]).setOpacity(0.3).get(),
    borderWidth: 0
  }]
}],
```

Here you can see an example how it can work:
http://jsfiddle.net/5ajoegb9/4/

Comment: Thank you, You saved my day! :)

Comment: Hi @Grzegorz Blachliński Thanks for your effort. Please help me one more time. I also want custom tool tip like image added in the question. I have already spent lots of time on Chart so I really appreciate your help.

Comment: I think in your case you should draw custom label using renderer.label and renderer.path: http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/Renderer.path

Comment: Yes, I have tried with the renderer.path but It's not displaying any line on the chart. I think it's conflict with the redraw. If i comment redraw code than line is appearing on the chart.

Comment: Hi @Grzegorz Blachliński, Can we add animation on this customized chart?

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't think it is simple way of adding animation to this kind of chart, because it is only workaround for adding gradients.